# URL redirection in Java return 302 instead of 301

Tags: java, redirect, http-status-code-301

I'm using this code to redirect url:

```
  response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
  response.sendRedirect(newURL);
```

what I can see is a correct redirection but the value returned in the response is 302 instead of 301. How can I force it to 301?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you use `sendRedirect`, it will reset the status to 302. You'll have to use setHeader to set the *Location* header yourself to redirect using a 301 status.

Example code:

```
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
response.setHeader("Location", "http://somewhere/");
```

Pulled from this answer:
[HttpServletResponse sendRedirect permanent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9034149/httpservletresponse-sendredirect-permanent)

Comment: I did it adding this: response.setHeader("Location", newUrl);  response.setHeader("Connection", "close"); but it doesn't work

Comment: Found the problem:) it's working now, I forgot to remove response.sendRedirect(newURL); sorry guys!

Comment: Hmm, actually sendRedirect accepts relative URLs and resolves them to an absolute URL. Explicitly setting Location -- as you suggest here -- does not have any resolution logic in place. Any suggested as-simple-as-possible way to resolve it correctly from relative to absolute path?