# HttpServletResponse sendRedirect permanent

Tags: java, servlets

This will redirect a request with a *temporary* 302 HTTP status code:

```
HttpServletResponse response;
response.sendRedirect("http://somewhere");
```

But is it possible to redirect it with a *permanent* 301 HTTP status code?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

You need to set the response status and the `Location` header manually.

```
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
response.setHeader("Location", "http://somewhere/");
```

Setting the status before `sendRedirect()` won't work as `sendRedirect()` would overridde it to `SC_FOUND` afterwards.

Comment: `Sends a temporary redirect response to the client using the specified redirect location URL.` Ok - you're right. I actually thought it would behave similar to the way it works with sendError after setting a status. Hence the 'try setting' in my post xD

Comment: The `sendError()` takes the status as argument, `sendRedirect()` not. It implicitly sets 302, regardless of the current status.

Comment: Thank you, this works.  To commit the response, you also have to flush the buffer: `response.flushBuffer();`

Comment: @k12345: the container ought to do this implicitly. Actually, you do not need to write anything to the response body.

Comment: @z12345 is right. Without  response.flushBuffer(); it does not work

Comment: @egemen: It may not be necessary. Either you're incorrectly continuing the code flow after having set the response status (e.g. forwarding to some JSP instead of returning from the method), or you've hit a bug in your server. In that case report issue to vendor of servletcontainer.

Answer (score -1):

I used the following code, but didn't worked for me.

```
String newURL = res.encodeRedirectURL("...");
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
response.sendRedirect(newURL);
```

then I tried this piece of code it worked for me

```
String newURL = res.encodeRedirectURL("...");
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
response.setHeader("Location", newURL);
```

this worked for me, I had the same issue

[how to set status to 301 while redirecting](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/servlets/http_status_code.shtml)