# forward from doPost() to doGet()

Tags: java, servlets

I am making a servlet for attendance. So in the `doGet()` method all the front end is displayed and if any error is generated ; i.e., something is left blank then the `doPost()` method should call the `doGet()` again for completing the blank spaces.

How can I call `doGet()` method from the same servlet's `doPost()`?

Comment: You should be able to find your answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/9034285/154527

Comment: This question is not a duplicate, how could they mark it as such? Linked question is different.

Answer (score 2):

If I take your question literally (i.e. invoke `doGet()` from `doPost()`), you can just invoke the `doGet()` method... it's a standard method like any other.

Here's a tip: When the `doPost()` and `doGet()` methods share a common set of logic, it's a good practice to isolate that logic into a separate (private) method that is to be invoked by all relevant `do***()` methods. For example:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  // GET-based logic
  processCommonLogic();
  // Other GET-based logic
}

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  // POST-based logic
  processCommonLogic();
  // Other POST-based logic
}

private void processCommonLogic() /* throws ServletException and/or IOException if needed */ {
  // Common logic
}
```

You can use this pattern to create a `processError()` method that can be invoked wherever you need it.

However, if the scope your question goes beyond invoking `doGet()` from `doPost()`, I suggest you have a look at the references pointed by Alain O'Dea.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, it's a simple

```
  this.doGet(req, resp);
  return;
```

However, it's not a best practice. Generally better to implement view logic as a JSP, and dispatch to it from the post logic...

```
  this. getServletConfig().getRequestDispatcher("my_view.jsp")
    .forward(req,resp);;
  return;
```

Or use `include()`, or an MVC framework like Struts...

Comment: Servlet invoking isn't taking place and also for some reason nothing is getting executed from the if statement even if I leave radio box unchecked

    doGet()
    
                rs.next();
       String uid1=rs.getString("uid");
       String name1=rs.getString("name");
       out.println("<tr><td>"+uid1+"</td><td>"+name1 +"</td><td>"+ "<input type='radio' name='att1' value='yes'>YES<input type='radio' name='att1' value='no'>NO"+"</td></tr>");
       
    doPost()
    
    `String att1 = request.getParameter("att1");
    if(att1=="")
    {
        doGet(request, response);
    }`