# SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY results in a 302

Tags: java, servlets, response, response.redirect

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [URL redirection in Java return 302 instead of 301](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756665/url-redirection-in-java-return-302-instead-of-301)

```
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
response.sendRedirect(redirectUrl);
```

I use this in my redirectcontroller to give the redirect 301 as status. But when I check the header of the page in a [header checker](http://www.webconfs.com/http-header-check.php) It gives a 302 (Moved Temporarily) as result.

Answer:

```
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
response.setHeader("Location", redirectUrl);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you're calling [`sendRedirect`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect%28java.lang.String%29) which is documented like this (emphasis mine):

> Sends a **temporary redirect** response to the client using the specified redirect location URL.

In other words, your first line is completely irrelevant when you explicitly call `sendRedirect`. If you want to be explicit about it, you can set the status, set the appropriate header and then just let the response end normally.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. What do I need to add to make it redirect with the 301?

Comment: @user1173655: As I said - set the relevant redirect URL header yourself (I can't remember what it is offhand), set the status as you're already doing, and it should be fine.

Comment: @HiddeBroerse How did you make it work, can you share it?. Me too facing the same issue.

Comment: @Abhiram the solution is in the duplicate thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756665/url-redirection-in-java-return-302-instead-of-301

Comment: @HiddeBroerse Thank you, will check on it